# How can I get the members of Bundle-Ether using snmp?

Tags: snmp, cisco, mib

I want using SNMP to get members of Bundle-Ether, but I can not find the suitable Mib for Bundle-Ether

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `ifStackStatus` entry in `IF-MIB::ifStackTable` . If you know ifIndex of Bundle-Ether, for example `173`, you can get lower-layer ifIndexes:

```
$ snmpwalk -v2c -c public 10.77.136.6 ifName.173
IF-MIB::ifName.173 = STRING: Bundle-Ether5
$ snmpwalk -v2c -c public 10.77.136.6 ifStackStatus.173
IF-MIB::ifStackStatus.173.72 = INTEGER: notInService(2)
IF-MIB::ifStackStatus.173.98 = INTEGER: active(1)
$ snmpget -v2c -c public 10.77.136.6 ifName.72 ifName.98 ifOperStatus.72 ifOperStatus.98
IF-MIB::ifName.72 = STRING: TenGigE0/1/0/0
IF-MIB::ifName.98 = STRING: TenGigE0/1/0/27
IF-MIB::ifOperStatus.72 = INTEGER: down(2)
IF-MIB::ifOperStatus.98 = INTEGER: up(1)
```